# RDPWrap "number of connections is limited"

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I've been using RDPWrap for years, but everytime I update the ini, I have trouble logging in concurrently. I get the "number of connections is limited" message. I always get it working again, but I can't figure it out this time. I replaced the ini and RDPConf.exe says it's fully supported. I've restarted Remote Desktop in Services and even restarted Windows. Is there a setting I need to change? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The ini I had allowed RDPConf.exe to show it as working, but I got the "number of connections is limited" message when trying to connect. The following post has a different ini that worked correctly for me:

https://github.com/fre4kyC0de/rdpwrap/issues/37#issuecomment-627914041